# Owin - Startup is throwing error

Tags: owin

While trying to integrate the below example in my solution I am getting the below issue.
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsStore

**Attempt to access method System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentedAttribute..ctor(System.String) in violation of security transparency rules failed.**

tried to add the key `<trust level="Full" />` but it doesn't work.
 Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I resolved it. 
I had this code in one of my assemblies (it is a custom implementation for Enterprise Library):

```
[assembly: Instrumented(@"root\EnterpriseLibrary")]
```

For some reason, the search for Owin Startup attribute does not like this